# Android: How to show a popup dialog after tapping the canvas for some time

Tags: android, canvas, dialog, popup, click

I am trying to output a popup dialog 5 seconds after clicking on the canvas. However my dialog appears immediately after I do a click on my canvas. How can i solve this?

My onTouch codes are as follows:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();

    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(getContext());
                    final EditText text = new EditText(getContext());

                    builder.setTitle("Change Name")
                            .setMessage("New Name").setView(text);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Change",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int i) {
                                    name = text.getText().toString();

                                }

                            });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int i) {
                                }

                            });
                    builder.create().show();

        }

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        sX = event.getX();
        sY = event.getY();
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        fX = event.getX();
        fY = event.getY();


        break;

    }// switch

    return true;

}// ontouch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using Handler with postDelayed like this:

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(getContext());
                    final EditText text = new EditText(getContext());

                    builder.setTitle("Change Name")
                            .setMessage("New Name").setView(text);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Change",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int i) {
                                    name = text.getText().toString();

                                }

                            });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int i) {
                                }

                            });
                    builder.create().show();
                }
            }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the documentation on [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html).